# Limiting a for Loop combined with a if statement jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops, if-statement, for-loop, fadeout

i got a tiny problem with my for loop in combine with a if statement
i want to count through the images and let them fadeIn or fadeOut after another
so lets take a look at my code:

```
$('#motive-toggler').click(function(){
var status = $('.thumb').css('display');
var count = $('#motive-wrapper > img').length;
var limit = 0;
var i = 0;

$('#motive-wrapper').css('display','block').appendTo('#control-wrapper');

if( status === 'none' ){
    for (i; i < count; i++){
        $('.thumb:eq('+i+')').delay(i*100).fadeIn(500);
    }
}
else {
    for (i; i > limit; i--){
        $('.thumb:eq('+i+')').delay(i*100).fadeOut(500);
    }
}
});
```

i counted the number of images (var count)
and i want to use this number in my for loop. so long so goood ;)
the fadeIn works perfectly but the fadeOut doesnt. theres no error message at all or anything i can work with. any ideas?

here's the markup:

```
<button id="motive-toggler" class="standard hover">m</button>
<div id="motive-wrapper">
    <img src="img/sample.png" class="thumb">
    <img src="img/sample.png" class="thumb">
    <img src="img/sample.png" class="thumb">
    <img src="img/sample.png" class="thumb">
</div>
```

thx for any help <3
and sorry for my bad englisch

Comment: `$('.thumb').css('display')` will only return value of first element in the collection. If it is not hidden when code runs will never return `none`

Comment: explain behavior wanted in full detail. Also set up demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: heres the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sNXb5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the for loop for `fadeOut`, you haven't given `i` an initial value. Try:

```
for (i = count - 1; i >= limit; i--) {
```

instead of

```
for (i; i > limit; i--){
```

**Update:**

If you want them to fade in the reverse order, try:

```
for (i = count - 1; i >= limit; i--){
    var fadeOrder = count - i - 1; // thumb 3 will go first, then thumb 2, etc
    $('.thumb:eq('+i+')').delay(fadeOrder*100).fadeOut(500);
}
```

It doesn't actually matter which way you loop through the thumbs, only what delay you give to each one. So you could instead do:

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
    var fadeOrder = count - i - 1; // thumb 3 will go first, then thumb 2, etc
    $('.thumb:eq('+i+')').delay(fadeOrder*100).fadeOut(500);
}
```

Comment: I LOVE U GUYS! now it works

thx for the quick help! :)
but i have another question:

it fades in starting by 0 and ending at 3 but why didnt it fadeOut starts at 3 and ends with 0? and reverses the trick

i would upvote but im to new here

Comment: @BillBronson I have added an update, which will fade in the reverse order

Comment: @BillBronson You're welcome, you too. If this (or a different answer on here) worked for you, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `i` starts out with value `0`; then you do a `while i > limit` and then you do `i--`.

But even at the first go, `i == limit`, so `i > limit` evaluates to `false`, and your loop is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

I was about the same to say as the other answers.

limit is 0 as i is, too. The for loop in the else statement is never true to begin looping.

Here is a JSFiddle with your code, but with bugfixes to make it work. Have Fun.

HTML:

```
<button id="motive-toggler" class="standard hover">m</button>
<div id="motive-wrapper">
    <img src="http://sodafilm.de/wp-content/uploads/earth-50x50.jpg" class="thumb">
    <img src="http://sodafilm.de/wp-content/uploads/earth-50x50.jpg" class="thumb">
    <img src="http://sodafilm.de/wp-content/uploads/earth-50x50.jpg" class="thumb">
    <img src="http://sodafilm.de/wp-content/uploads/earth-50x50.jpg" class="thumb">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumb{
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#motive-toggler').click(function(){
var status = $('.thumb').css('display');
var count = $('#motive-wrapper > img').length;
var limit = 0;
var i = 0;

$('#motive-wrapper').css('display','block').appendTo('#control-wrapper');

if( status === 'none' ){
    for (i; i < count; i++){
    $('.thumb:eq('+i+')').delay(i*100).fadeIn(500);
}}else{
    i = count;
    for (i; i >= limit; i--){
    $('.thumb:eq('+i+')').delay(i*100).fadeOut(500);
}}
});
```

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/B5ZYJ/7/

Answer (score 0):

Your fadeOuts start at the front instead of the other way around. This is because when you are fadingOut, you start at 3 then 2, 1, 0. and your `delay(i*100)` is doing `delay 300, 200, 100, 0` so if you put `(count - i - 1)` then your delay will flip and will turn into `delay 0, 100, 200, 300`

http://jsfiddle.net/dLS4e/1

```
$('#motive-toggler').click(function(){
var status = $('.thumb').css('display');
var count = $('#motive-wrapper > img').length;
var limit = 0;
var i = 0;

$('#motive-wrapper').css('display','block').appendTo('#control-wrapper');

if ( status === 'none' ) {
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++){
        $('.thumb:eq('+i+')').delay( i * 100 ).fadeIn(500);
    }
} else {
    for (var i = count - 1; i >= limit; i--) {
        $('.thumb:eq('+i+')').delay( (count - i - 1) * 100).fadeOut(500);
    }
}

});
```